# Get the ID of a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

So, I'm already trying this for a week, still errors. Can get the spreadsheet ID properly.

```
Currently I have this code:

    function getSS(e,getSS) {

//If not yet authorized - get current spreadsheet

      if (e && e.authMode != ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL) {
        var getSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      } 

//Else if authorized set/get property to open spreadsheet by ID for time-driven triggers

else {
        if(!PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('SOURCE_DATA_ID')){
        PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('SOURCE_DATA_ID', e.source.getId());  
        }
        var getSSid = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('SOURCE_DATA_ID');
        var getSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getSSid);
      }
      return getSS;
    }

    var SS = getSS();
```

It's supposed to get active spreadsheet ID when the addon is not yet authorized, and get a spreadsheet ID from properties when it's authorized. However, when testing as installed, I always get an error that I don't have permission to use `openById()` or `getDocumentProperties()`

How do I keep SS as global variable without it being null in any authMode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it this way:

```
    //Because onInstall() only runs once and user might want to launch addon in different spreadsheets I moved getting ID to onOpen(), 

    function onInstall (e) {
      getAuthUrl();
      onOpen(e);
    }
```

Cases for different AuthModes.

```
    function onOpen(e) {

    var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();

      if (e && e.authMode === ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {

      menu.addItem('Authorize this add-on', 'auth');

      } 
      else {

    //If addon is authorized add menu with functions that required it. Also get the id of the current spreadsheet and save it into properties, for use in other functions.

      menu.addItem('Run', 'run');  

      var ssid = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
      var docProps = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
      docProps.setProperty('SOURCE_DATA_ID', ssid);
      }
      menu.addToUi();
    }
```

Function that pops authorization window:

```
function getAuthUrl() {
  var authInfo,msg;

  authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
  msg = 'This addon needs authorization to work properly on this spreadsheet.  Click ' +
    'this url to authorize: <br><br>' + 
      '<a href="' + authInfo.getAuthorizationUrl() +
      '" style="cursor:pointer;padding:5px;background: #4285f4;border:1px #000;text-align: center;margin-top: 15px;width: calc(100% - 10px);font-weight: 600;color: #fff">AUTHORIZE</a>' +      
      '<br><br> This spreadsheet needs to either ' +
      'be authorized or re-authorized.';

  //return msg;//Use this for testing

  //ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL is the auth mode to check for since no other authorization mode requires
  //that users grant authorization
  if (authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus() === ScriptApp.AuthorizationStatus.REQUIRED) {
    return msg;
  } else {
    return "No Authorization needed";
  };
  console.info('Authorization window called');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that global variables are constructed each and every time that Apps Script project is loaded / used. Also note that no parameters are passed to functions automatically - you have to designate a function as either a simple trigger (special function name) or an installed trigger before Google will send it an argument, and in all other cases you have to explicitly specify the argument.

The problem is then that you declare `var SS = getSS();` in global scope, and do not pass it any parameters (there are no parameters you could pass it, either). Thus in the definition of `getSS()`, even if you have it as `function getSS(e) {`, there is no input argument to bind to the variable `e`.

Therefore this criteria `if (e && ...)` is **always** `false`, because `e` is `undefined`, which means your `else` branch is always executed. In your `else` branch, you assume that you have permissions, and your test never was able to even try to check that. Hence, your errors. You might have meant to write `if (!e || e.authMode !== ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL)` which is true if *either* of the criteria is true. Consider reviewing JavaScript Logical Operators.

While you don't share how your code uses this spreadsheet, I'm quite certain it doesn't need to be available as an evaluated global. Any place you use your `SS` variable, you could have simply used `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` instead.

Your `getSS()` function additionally force the use of a permissive scope by using `openById` - you cannot use the preferred `...spreadsheets.currentonly` scope.

Example add-on code:

```
function onInstall(e) {
  const wb = e.source;
  const docProps = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  docProps.setProperty('SOURCE_DATA_ID', wb.getId());
  /**
   * set other document properties, create triggers, etc.
   */
  // Call the normal open event handler with elevated permissions.
  onOpen(e);
}
function onOpen(e) {
  if (!e || e.authMode === ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    // No event object, or we have no permissions.
  } else {
    // We have both an event object and either LIMITED or FULL AuthMode.
  }
}
```

Consider reviewing the Apps Script guide to add-on authorization and setup: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle

Comment: there are few good points in your answer. would you please help me a little bit more. You say that I have to put triggers in onInstall(), is that really a good idea? I'm afraid of two situations - when add-on is updated will it get new triggers from oninstall, or is uninstall only triggered once? also is uninstall triggered on every spreadsheet authorization action or only on download from the store?

Comment: other issue, I selected test as addon, and choosed installed but not enabled. I managed to successfully see the authorize addon menu item, when I click on it I get the authorization popup and authorize it. Then I'm having AuthMode Full, but in the menu it's still the only one authorization item. Is it ok behavior for pre-release testing and will be fine on prod test?

Comment: and a third one, related to prod testing.  I have it already on chrome web store, and I have tester account set. But when I open the addon link from tester account it gives 404, while it's published.

Comment: Comments on an answer to a specific question are not where you should ask entirely new questions. The code I provide is solely an example showing how you can test and things you could do in those particular conditionally-executed blocks. The example I provide is in no way a substitute for you reviewing, understanding, and testing in your actual dev environment. If this answer of mine addresses the question you asked, upvote and accept it. If it is not useful w.r.t. the question you asked, downvote it and/or use comments to help me realize that it doesn't address the question you asked.

Comment: no it doesn't work. it works locally, but when published and tested from tester account it gives `Invalid argument: id` with no reference to the line.

Comment: @SamTyurenkov that sounds like an entirely unrelated question to the one asked here.

Comment: I didn't ask any question in my last comment. I just stated that your solution returns an error.